# swipelayout working but no feed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragment, swipe

I am using swipelayout from daimajia.I get some data from services.When the service has a date than will visible an icon that will open the left sideBut it do nothing when clicking the icon.I have no error that's the reason why cannot resolve it.The action is when clicking the icon,that visible a textview and start a chronometer.

Here is my swipeListener

```
private SwipeListener swipeListener = new SwipeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onStartOpen(SwipeLayout layout, SwipeLayout.DragEdge edge) {
        if (edge == SwipeLayout.DragEdge.Left && viewHolder.discountText != null) {
            **viewHolder.discountText.setTimeByTag().play();**
            LogUtils.LogE("Left Open...");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(SwipeLayout layout, SwipeLayout.DragEdge edge) {
        super.onOpen(layout, edge);
        if (edge == SwipeLayout.DragEdge.Left && viewHolder.discountText != null) {
            viewHolder.discountText.setTimeByTag().play();
            LogUtils.LogE("Left Open...");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClose(SwipeLayout layout, SwipeLayout.DragEdge edge) {
        if (edge == SwipeLayout.DragEdge.Left && viewHolder.discountText != null) {
            viewHolder.discountText.stop();
            LogUtils.LogE("Left Close!");
        }
    }
};

public void openLeft() {
        LogUtils.LogE("onClick openLeft-");
        if (getSwipeLayout() == null){
            LogUtils.LogE("onClick -null-");
            return;
        }


        if (!getSwipeLayout().isOpen()) {
            getSwipeLayout().open(true, SwipeLayout.DragEdge.Left);
            LogUtils.LogE("onClick --");
        }
    }
```

all the codes working in other my fragments.I need some idea what's the reason that it not give true action that swipe to left.

**EDIT:**
 Here is the Logs:
[image: Log SwipeLayout.]

In this picture I have 2 items there which it's in my favorite page.The last one item has end date that will be visible the icon(ImageView).When pressing the icon,it should swipe to left side but it's not working and give the result like this picture which I'm shared.

**EDIT**
There is something more.I had looked the codes in debug mode and give here an message:[image]

but put define swipeLayout into my code:

```
sl.setShowMode(SwipeLayout.ShowMode.LayDown);
sl.setDragEdges(SwipeLayout.DragEdge.Left, SwipeLayout.DragEdge.Right);
sl.setBottomViewIds(R.id.productBottomLeft, R.id.productBottomRight,   SwipeLayout.EMPTY_LAYOUT, SwipeLayout.EMPTY_LAYOUT);
```

Comment: Can you also share the output of logs while you run in application, so that we can see what's happening and what's not?

Comment: Ok, in this case, i would suggest you to check open method because after "onClick openLeft" there should've been "Left Open..." from listener, something's up right there.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView button = SwipeLayout.findViewById(R.id.yourButtonId) //the bottom view;
button.setOnClickListener(v -> yourMethod());
```